Do metal objects attract lightning?
I have come across various sources that claim that you should stay away from metal objects (umbrellas, bikes, etc) during thunderstorms because they "attract lightning". One example would be this text from ARD, a public and well respected German TV station.

Sobald ein Gewitter aufzieht, Finger weg von metallenen Gegenständen. Walking- und Wanderstöcke, Golfschläger sowie Eispickel und Karabiner gehören mindestens fünf Meter weit weg. Das gilt natürlich auch für einen ganz normalen Regenschirm - auch wenn es regnet. Der Regenschirm zieht wegen seines Metallskeletts Blitze an.

My rough translation (emphasis also mine).

When a thunderstorm approaches, hands off any metal items. Walking-sticks, golf clubs, ice picks or snap hooks have to be put at least 5m away. This of course also applies to normal umbrellas - even if it rains. The umbrella attracts lightning due to its metal skeleton.

I have a hard time believing that a small metal object like an umbrella will have a significant impact on where lightning strikes. There are als official websites that state that it is a myth that metal attracts lightning, although some acknowledge that being in contact with metal objects can cause more severe injuries if one is struck.
I am looking for recent, trustworthy sources, preferably peer-reviewed, scientific publications, that answer the following questions:

Does being in touch with a metal object like an umbrella or a bicycle increase the odds of you getting hit by lightning?
Does being in touch with a metal object increase the severity of injuries if you are hit by lightning?

PS: I am aware of this question regarding use of mobile phones during thunderstorms but did not find the answer to my exact questions there.

The use of the word "attracting" might be a little problematic. As a simplified casual term it is maybe OK but it might seriously misrepresent the physical mechanism involved. It might be better to ask whether holding such an object increases the likelihood of being struck during a storm (as this doesn't presuppose a mechanism).

The "official website" says "Myth: Structures with metal, or metal on the body (jewelry, cell phones,Mp3 players, watches, etc), attract lightning.
Fact: Height, pointy shape, and isolation are the dominant factors controlling where a lightning bolt will strike. The presence of metal makes absolutely no difference on where lightning strikes.".  I.e. coins in your pocket don't matter, but holding an umbrella in the air does. ¶ There really isn't any notable claim here.

Making a slightly easier path to ground (and a pointy one in particular) most certainly does increase the probability of initiating high voltage breakdown (i.e. lightning). There is a reason, after all, why lightning rods are, well, rods...

The original claim is "metal attracts lightning" which I translated as "touching a metal object does increase the chance of getting struck". I would say this is a testable claim?

That "Lightning Myths" website looks extremely sketchy. Their last two "Facts" are not contrary to their "Myths". They seem to think the statement "The presence of metal makes absolutely no difference on where lightning strikes" is supported by the fact that trees and mountains are struck. Just because it's .gov doesn't mean they didn't just get some intern to write it. I guarantee you that holding a conducting rod up into the air increases your chance of getting struck more than holding an insulating rod.

The umbrella claim is arguably true, but for the wrong reasons. The umbrella itself increases your effective height and makes it more likely that ‘you’ end up being close enough to the leader (the initial downwards discharge that forms the plasma channel the return stroke travels along) that you get struck instead of the ground. But that’s only if there’s nothing taller nearby with a similar or lesser dielectric strength (and if you’re not standing out in the middle of a field in the countryside).

@JounceCracklePop in the rain, aren't all rods conducting rods?

@MarkRansom more like potentially conductive streams of water on a rod

There's a theory that lightning rods don't work by diverting the lightning, but by providing a slow discharge path to ground, so that the area near the protected building is less charged than surrounding areas.  Come to think of it, I don't remember ever seeing a melted lightning rod.

Are you really asking whether small quantities of metal attract lightning in or of themselves or whether, all other things being equal, small quantities of metal might make draw the lightning left or right, in front or back?

From Lightning Science: Five Ways Lightning Strikes People:

Metal does not attract lightning, but it provides a path for the lightning to follow. Most indoor lightning casualties and some outdoor casualties are due to conduction. Whether inside or outside, anyone in contact with anything connected to metal wires, plumbing, or metal surfaces that extend outside is at risk. This includes anything that plugs into an electrical outlet, water faucets and showers, corded phones, and windows and doors

and Lightning Myths:

Myth: Structures with metal, or metal on the body (jewelry, cell phones,Mp3 players, watches, etc), attract lightning.
Fact: Height, pointy shape, and isolation are the dominant factors controlling where a lightning bolt will strike. The presence of metal makes absolutely no difference on where lightning strikes. Natural objects that are tall and isolated, but are made of little to no metal, like trees and mountains get struck by lightning many times a year. When lightning threatens, take proper protective action immediately by seeking a safe shelter and don’t waste time removing metal. While metal does not attract lightning, it does conduct it so stay away from metal fences, railing, bleachers, etc.

Trying to make this simple: Lightning is lazy: while it's still in the air it will follow the shortest path to ground and when it has struck it will generally continue the path of lowest impedance until it has dissipated.
The location where lightning strikes will almost always be determined by the shortest path to ground. This will often be any "sticky outy" object that's near by: tall buildings, church steeples, trees, posts, ship's masts, etc. This is completely independent of what material this strike point is made off, it only matters that it is the shortest path.
Metal can make a difference on what happens next. The reason we have lightning rods is that they provide a very low impedance path for the lightning to go into the Earth. So the lightning travels mostly through the metal lightning rod and not through more valuable or vulnerable objects. Touching metal that is connected to Earth ground is generally not a good idea since this is preferred path for lightning. Touching isolated metal objects makes no difference whatsoever.

Does being in touch with a metal object like an umbrella or a bicycle increase the odds of you getting hit by lightning?

That depends a bit on the detail. If the metal objects have good ground connection and/or are sticking out above other nearby objects, than yes. Sticking out your umbrella with a metal tip when standing on a flat field is not so good. Holding the same umbrella when standing on the ground between two skyscrapers is perfectly fine.
Umbrellas don't have ground connectivity. Bicycle tires are good insulators but other parts like kick stand, frame touching a post, chain that connects it to a metal fence are not.

Does being in touch with a metal object increase the severity of injuries if you are hit by lightning?

Again, that depends a lot on the details: what exactly is the metal connected to and how high does it protrude. House wiring is very well grounded and it protrudes high in the house, so this is a concern. Holding a metal pen is no concern at all.
One more note based on the comments (if that's ok)
The physics behind lightning are rather complicated. It's guided by Maxwell's laws, material properties (under normal and high energy conditions), a highly dynamic and nonlinear set of equations, and the exact boundary conditions (geometry, material, layout) of the environment, which is dynamically changed by the lightning itself during its discharge.
Any "rule thumb" will therefore require significant simplification and approximation and you will always be able to find or construct use cases where that rule is wrong or misleading. Hence my simplification "metal that's isolated is generally ok to touch. Metal that as good connectivity to ground or other low impedance thingies you should leave alone". It's not perfect but more useful then "lighting will follow the steepest gradient in the Electric Field which is dynamically reshaped by the discharge"

A metal object that you touch may be part of a good path to ground, and if you are grounded the strike may find another path. Zap!

XKCD's Randall Munroe wrote a blog post about the process of lightning seeking ground, including some helpful visualizations of what "sticky outy" means in practice. (And a really cool video.)

@dim: lightning will go through pretty much anything, but it will choose the path of least resistance. You want to make sure you are NOT in this path (or close to it).

"Choose the path of least resistance" is more accurate than "shortest part to ground". The reason lightning seems to not be "attracted" to metal is because just about everything has less resistance than air. Hold a pen up to the same height as your finger right next to it and sure, lightning is more likely, slightly, to choose the conductive pen. You're still not gonna like how that feels when the lightning comes out the other end of the pen into your hand. What it's not likely to do is choose the empty air next to you. Compared to air, you are very nearly as tempting as the pen.

@Hilmar - this is the only time, in my life, I have seen you make an oddball post.  Drunk like me?! :)  "The reason we have lighting rods is that they provide a very low impedance path for the lightning to go into the Earth. [ie the lighting is attracted to the metal and not to the wood] So the lightning travels [ie the lighting is attracted to the metal and not to the wood] mostly through the metal lighting rod  [ie the lighting is attracted to the metal and not to the wood] and not through more valuable or vulnerable objects. [ie the lighting is attracted to the metal and not to the wood]"

I'm not sure if it's quite true that lightning will choose the path of least resistance. I think if you had a wooden post and a metal hemisphere nearby each other, both of the same height, lightning would be more likely to strike the wooden post because it has a stronger electric field around it due to its pointier shape. I don't think the lightning has any way to "know" that the metal is a better conductor. But I could be wrong—maybe as the lightning leader approaches, it will cause the charge in the metal hemisphere to redistribute somehow.

@Cadence if you mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1mB5rM8WHU which was linked to from the xkcd post, the video is no longer available, sadly. I don't suppose you have anther link to it?

@SophieSwett lighting absolutely chooses the path of least resistance. But complicating that idea is that the leader itself changes the path of least resistance while it randomly flails around trying to find it.

I wonder if the truth is a little more nuanced, since low-resistance, grounded objects also facilitate the flow of positive ions upward toward the negatively charged stepped leader during lightning formation.  By doing so, they influence the point that the leader ultimately connects, so could very well be said to "attract lightning".

https://www.weather.gov/safety/lightning-science-connection-ground

Thanks a lot for the answer! This was quite insightful. Could you may be provide a few references for the second part?

If you happen to touch the metal wire that is grounded, isn't it dangerous as it will probably get hot or even melt due to high current. I've seen a documentary on electric security : a man had his hand severly burnt because he mistakenly held the wire of an ampermeter (instead of volmeter) wanting to measure tension on a high voltage installation. Short circuit, the wire melted.

Aren't you contradicting yourself? Metal is a good conductor and therefore attracts lightning (or as you say "it provides a path for the lightning to follow" which is the same as attracting).

@paddotk When people mention "attracting", it could imply an action at a distance, meaning the presence of a metal object could change the path the leader takes before reaching said metal object. Except that is not what is happening. A good conductor only implies that given two paths, electricity will follow the one with the smallest resistance, but it needs to reach said metal object in the first place. Conduction is not the same as attraction.

@Entropy How does the lightning reach a point then? If the lightning would go for a metal object rather than a close-by slightly higher point, I would definitely call that attracting.

This seems at odds with the purpose and concept of a lightning rod.  On the other hand, I'm not aware of ever seeing an actual lightning rod installed.

@Entropy The presence of the conductive object does influence the path the leader takes, because positive charges move upward from the ground through and from the conductive, grounded object. Those positive charges literally attract the negative charges in the leader (through the EM force) and influence the path it takes to ground. They "light the way" to (and dynamically change!) the path of least resistance.

Lightning is complicated and I don't think there's a simple, straightforward answer to this.  I found a really detailed paper about this and it has a lot of detailed content while also being relatively easy to follow.  I encourage people to read the full paper here: The physics of lightning.  I found it really informative and helped disabuse me of my own incorrect notions.
First off, the most lightning never reaches the ground:

All lightning discharges can be divided into two categories: (1) those that bridge the gap between the cloud charge and the Earth and (2) those that do not. The latter group as a whole is referred to as “cloud discharges” and accounts for the majority of all lightning discharges.

The question is about lightning strikes that might strike a person, who is presumably on or near the ground so we can focus on the minority: category (1) above.
Summarizing from the article:

About 90% of cloud-to-ground lightning flashes are initiated by a negatively-charged, downward-propagating leader
About 10% of cloud-to-ground lightning flashes are initiated by a positively-charged, downward propagating leader
The remaining two types of cloud-to-ground (actually ground-to-cloud) lightning discharges are relatively uncommon and are upward initiated from mountaintops, tall man-made towers, or other tall objects, towards the cloud charge regions

The last point is interesting, I think, but upward lightning is rare and wouldn't typically be a risk to a person unless they were on one of these objects, and I think most people understand that the top of a cellphone tower during a lightning storm is a risky place to be.  So we can ignore those as well.  This leaves the 'downward strikes'.  For brevity, we will also ignore the less common positive 'downward strikes' and focus on the most common cloud-to-earth strikes:

The physical mechanism for moving the negative charge to Earth is a propagating electrical discharge called the “stepped leader”.

This is mechanism is explained as:

The stepped leader’s movement from cloud to ground is not continuous, but rather it moves downward in discrete luminous segments of tens of meters length, then pauses, then moves another “step”, and so on.

Presumably, this gives lightning its characteristic zig-zag appearance.  Skipping ahead, we get to the part that is relevant to the question:

When the stepped leader is near the ground, its relatively large negative charge induces (attracts) concentrated positive charge on the conducting Earth beneath it and especially on objects projecting above the Earth’s surface.

The key word 'attracts' appears but to be clear, it is not saying that the objects attract the lightning, but rather that the nearing negative charge causes the ground and objects on the ground to become net-positively charged.  To understand this, it's crucial to understand that the earth is, in general, assumed to have a neutral charge.  That is, negative and positive charges are balanced.  When a large negative charge comes near the  ground, that balance is disrupted as the negative charges in the ground are repelled and positive charges are attracted.

When the electric field intensity near ground from these charges becomes large enough, upward-going, positively-charged electrical discharges from the ground or from grounded objects will be initiated, ... One of these upward-going discharges will contact a branch of the downward-moving leader, thereby determining the lightning strike-point and the primary lightning current path (channel) between cloud and ground.

That last bit is important here.  The final path to ground is determined by which object or point on the ground initiates the upward positive discharge.  So it makes sense that an object that is taller is likely to be closer to the downward leader, in which case, the field strength will be stronger at points on that object that at the ground surface.
And finally:

Understanding the “attachment process” is critical to the proper design of lightning protection systems. Unfortunately, the attachment process is sufficiently complex and variable that it has not been possible to gain more than a relatively crude understanding of it.

So, the answer is complicated. Logically, though, conductivity of the object(s) in question would influence how easily an 'upward-going discharge' will be initiated through that object.  So, while the initial claim may not be strictly correct, I think saying it is strictly false is more wrong.  Holding a aluminum pole over your head in a lightning storm might be more dangerous than holding an insulating pole of the same length but neither is advisable.

Probably worth mentioning that few things are good insulators once they're all wet from the rain.  Not good conductors, either, but very little current is used in the creation of the path, and once the current builds up, its path has already been defined.

No, metal objects do not attract lightning in the sense that a force is excerted on the lightning pulling it to the metal rod.
The physical process is this: A potential difference or voltage is build up between the clouds and the earth. When this voltage is high enough elektrons are pulled from their atoms in the air and propelled to the positive potential. The electrons are accelerated and then ionize other atoms in their path.The moving elektrons constitute an electrical current. In the path of the current electrical energy is converted to heat and the heated atoms produce light. This is what we call lightning.
Sticking a metal rod in the air shortens the distance between clouds and earth, and thus increases the possibillity of the atoms being ionized as the electrical field between earth and clouds increases. This will not happen with a insulator rod, as the distance between the clouds and lowest potential (earth) is not shortened.
See M.A. Uman. All about lightning, Dover Publications Inc. New York, 1986

Welcome to Skeptics! Please provide some references to support your claims.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/580/why-does-lightning-strike-from-the-ground-up

Maybe it's just the lack of citations but from a physics perspective, this is pretty right on. The only qualm I have is the part of about how it starts from the ground.  I don't think it's really sensible to talk about it starting from one side or the other.  A really good analog is a florescent bulb. The way the plasma is formed to produce light works in much the same way as lightning.

@JimmyJames: "from a physics perspective, this is pretty right on" - perhaps you would like to add some references that shows how you know it. (A handwave at an entire book - a 1987 reprint of a 1971 introductory pop science book from 40-50 years ago - isn't a great place for our readers to be able to confirm this is empirically accurate.)

@Oddthinking "A handwave at an entire book - a 1987 reprint of a 1971 introductory pop science book from 40-50 years ago - isn't a great place for our readers to be able to confirm this is empirically accurate." I agree.  I think that standard should also apply to a website without any scientific citations as, well however.

@JimmyJames: Indeed. We recommend that people quote the sources to show that it directly supports the claim and ideally mention how the source reached that conclusion (e.g. it was a study, textbook etc)
